# Documentation Bug: "Data was corrupted. Please try again"

Tags: bug, documentation

I created a new topic while moving an example in the Documentation. But I can't save the topic because of a error message: "Data was corrupted. Please try again."

Here's the draft I'm trying to save: 
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/drafts/72223

As you can see there's no corrupt data on the draft. To make sure, I rewrote the example. However it still doesn't save.

Comment: there aren't any pipe | symbols in your example, right?

Comment: No. I saw that was a possible error. So already checked for that.